# Creating a box plot on r and want to combine

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm creating a boxplot on r using ggplot. I created 2 different lines of code and want to put into the same graph to compare data from 2019 and 2020. However, with Youtube videos they say to add "~" anyone know what's wrong?

code I'm using

```
ggplot(covid, aes(x=covid1$oct2019_rent, y=covid1$Depression.2019))+ geom_boxplot()~ ggplot(covid, aes(x=covid1$oct2020_rent, y=covid1$Depression.2020)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you mind providing [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of job, I use the [patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/patchwork.html) package. Your code will be something like.

```
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(covid, aes(x=covid1$oct2019_rent, y=covid1$Depression.2019))+ geom_boxplot()
p2 <- ggplot(covid, aes(x=covid1$oct2020_rent, y=covid1$Depression.2020)) + geom_boxplot()

p1 / p2
```

There are some examples that you can ajust for your needs.